# Como desplegar una aplicación React Typescript Express Server a Firebase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, express

Tengo una aplicación React Typescript y la tengo subida a Firebase.
Debido a problemas con SEO tuve que configurarla con "express" para realizar Server Side Rendering.

Ahora tengo la parte SSR corriendo en local con `node server` correctamente pero no encuentro la manera de deployarla a Firebase para que me cargue esta versión.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Si no, ¿Alguien sabe de algún hosting gratis/barato para empezar un proyecto y como puedo desplegar esta app?

Utilizo React 18

Gracias!